# PHP Wordpress Functions.PHP get instance of class (variable undefined in header.php)

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

functions.php

```
final class Test {

     public function helloworld() {
       return "Hello World!";
     }

}

$testy = new Test;
```

When i try to call $testy->helloworld(); inside my header.php file it does give me a error like variable undefined.

When i call the instance $testy inside my header php like this `<?php global $testy; ?>` and then use the instance with the function helloworld() everything is working fine but i need to call it again in my footer to let that instance work also for my footer.

So i want to know how i can code it in my functions.php without declaring it inside my header.php and footer.php.

Hopefully someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
final class Test {

     public function helloworld() {
       return "Hello World!";
     }

}

$testy = new Test;

$_GLOBAL['testy'] = $testy;


?>
```

Comment: and is there another way?

Comment: and how can i select the function helloworld() with the $_GLOBAL?